# how to determine if two numbers are relatively prime in prolog

Tags: prolog, primes

How can you determine in prolog that two numbers are relatively primes? Does anyone know if there is a function for this or you have to write it? I searched for it in the documentation, but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: There's a built-in arithmetic function: `X is gcd(10,34).` To determine if A and B are relatively prime, you'd check, `1 is gcd(A,B).`.

Comment: Thank you, this didn't come into my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mbratch mentioned in comments, there is a standard gcd (greatest common divisor) function.

Relatively prime numbers has gcd equal to 1.

So the code of relatively_prime can be very simple:

```
relatively_prime(X, Y) :-
    gcd(X, Y) =:= 1.
```

Comment: Nit: `gcd/1` is not a standard function. Many have it, though.